# Como adicionar um botão no Action Bar?

Tags: android

Gostaria de colocar apenas um botão no ´Action Bar´.

segue uma imagem de exemplo da internet.

[image: imagem da internet.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você precisa adicionar um método chamado **onCreateOptionsMenu**, exemplo:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
   getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
   return true;
}
```

Dentro do diretório **res**, você deve criar o diretório **menu**, e dentro do diretório **menu**, você cria o arquivo **main.xml**.

Segue um exemplo do XML do menu:

```
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <item 
        android:id="@+id/action_back" 
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_back"
        android:orderInCategory="100" 
        app:showAsAction="always" />

</menu>
```

Cada **item** que você adicionar no XML, será um botão na sua **ActionBar**.